# Ansible synchronize module mode=pull to save into /tmp/<hostname>/<filename>

Tags: ansible

With mode=pull, I want to fetch and save remote files to the "dest" directory per hostname under the same top-level directory tree.

This is what I want:

```
src=/proc/cpuinfo (of every Ansible inventory host)

dest=/tmp/host1/cpuinfo, /tmp/host2/cpuinfo, /tmp/host3/cpuinfo, etc. (of the Ansible master)
```

If I do,

```
ansible all -m synchronize 'src=/proc/cpuinfo dest=/tmp/cpuinfo mode=pull'
```

/tmp/cpuinfo file on the Ansible master (= dest) gets overwritten by every remote host's cpuinfo file and I get to see only the very last one.

That is, I want a similar behavior as if I run

```
ansible all -m fetch -a 'src=/proc/cpuinfo dest=/tmp/cpuinfo'
```

Thank you in advance!

- Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can do this with single ad-hoc command.

```
ansible all -m synchronize -a 'src=/proc/cpuinfo dest=/tmp/{{inventory_hostname}}/cpuinfo mode=pull'
```

could do the thing, but you must create `/tmp/<hostname>` directories in advance, because `rsync` doesn't create non-existent directories for you. And you can't use ansible facts (like `ansible_hostname` and `ansible_fqdn`) as parameters for ad-hoc module execution - only "predefined" variables (like `inventory_hostname`).

Update: playbook code

```
- file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    state: directory
  delegate_to: localhost
- synchronize:
    src: /proc/cpuinfo
    dest: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/cpuinfo"
    mode: pull
```

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin. I gave an example of the ad-hoc execution but I want to use the synchronize module in playbooks.

Comment: added playbook snippet

Comment: Thanks but what I want is /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }} to be created on the Ansible master so that remote files can be saved in /tmp/server1/proc/cpuinfo, /tmp/server2/proc/cpuinfo, etc., just like how the fetch module behaves but to rather copy directories as well to Ansible master (because the fetch module cannot copy directories).

Comment: Yes, sorry – I've missed the `delegate_to` option – edited my answer. No directory is created on Ansible host instead of remote host.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again, Konstantin. I did more intense search and found out another way to do it. (Added below)

Answer (score 0):

(Original poster)

Another way to do it using the synchronize module only:

```
  - synchronize:
      src: "{{ item.src }}"
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      mode: pull
    with_items:
      - { src: '/proc/cpuinfo', dest: '/tmp/testing/{{ inventory_hostname }}/proc' }
      - { src: '/proc/meminfo', dest: '/tmp/testing/{{ inventory_hostname }}/proc' }
      - { src: '/etc/services', dest: '/tmp/testing/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc' }
```

Comment: This will not throw error only if `/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}` exists.

Comment: As long as the parent directory (/tmp/testing) exists, it'll create every {{ inventory_hostname }} subdirectory under the parent directory. It worked for me. That is, using the file module is not needed to create {{ inventory_hostname }} subdirectory with this way.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought it worked. As I just did a fresh testing after deleting the previous directory structure, it didn't work. I'll delete this section after I did some more testing to confirm.